# How to reach data size of process?

Tags: c, ubuntu, process

Firstly I'm a beginner. Sorry if it's a super easy question. I want to print the start address and size of data, heap and stack of a process.

Is `proc.c` that I wrote a process too ? If it is, on terminal of Ubuntu I enter `size proc` and the output is :

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   2344     648       8    3000     bb8 proc
```

I want to reach 648. I tried `FILE *f = fopen("/proc/self/status","r");` and read the values and print them. The output is:

```
3747  1  93981426002365  140462117988768  0  32765  93981426002288
```

I couldn't reach data of my process which is 648. How can I reach it ?

Comment: by "reach data size" I mean  "648" as I said. No idea behind `/proc/self/status` :D Just wanted to try something I found, I don't even know what does it do. So I just want to reach that 648

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean